# How do I execute an arbitrary script with a working directory of the directory its in?

Tags: linux, bash, groovy

I need to execute a groovy script file from bash, and I need the script to have a working directory of the directory it exists in.

That is, in my bash script, I'm doing this:

```
/opt/script/myscript.groovy &
```

But this seems to set the working directory to `/etc/init.d`, the directory I'm calling from. How do I change the working directory for that script to `/opt/script`?

Comment: The answer is here in some form or another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in

Comment: @Chris: Except it's not. Arbitrary script implies *not bash*. Bash specific answers will be downvoted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `/etc/init.d`

probably you are runnig (starting) that script from `/etc/init.d`?

Add `cd /opt/script` at the first line of the script

OR

...to keep it dynamic, add:
`cd "$(dirname "$0")"`

Comment: Easy enough. CD'ing before the rest of the script works fine.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using start-stop-daemon inside your /etc/init.d script, you can take advantage of the -d parameter for achieving this:

```
   -d, --chdir path
          Chdir to path before starting the process. This is done after the chroot if the -r|--chroot option is set. When not specified, start-stop-daemon will chdir to the root directory before starting the process.
```

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` putting that in the script works best:

```
HERE=$(cd -- $(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}) > /dev/null && pwd)
cd -- "$HERE"
```

This will succeed even with the following invocation (of `/path/to/script.sh`):

```
PATH="/path/to:$PATH" bash script.sh
```

where `HERE=$(dirname $0)` would fail.

Optionally you could also use `pwd -P` instead of just `pwd`, then `$HERE` will contain the realpath (canonicalized absolute pathname) as of `man 3 realpath`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
SCRIPT=/opt/script/myscript.groovy
pushd `dirname $SCRIPT`
./`basename $SCRIPT`
popd
```

Comment: The `popd` isn't necessary in any environment except a DOS .BAT file; what a process does to change directory cannot affect the directory of the program that runs it.