# Python sys.stdout not working for init.d script

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have a very simple problem. A python script starting with the following:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open("server.out", 'w')
```

If I enter this command directly to the terminal

```
python start_server.py &
```

It writes the `server.out` file.
If I enter `service tdserver start`, all the `init.d` script does is this:

```
python start_server.py &
```

The same command, nothing else. Yet, in this case the stdout doesnt get written to `server.out`

Why? No processes have lock on the file, confirmed that the script is stopped with `ps -aux`

Comment: please try using full-path for the filename, e.g. open("/tmp/server.out", 'w') and check if you find the file in /tmp

Comment: It fixed my problem. I wonder what the default exec dir would be. Please add it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comment:

You were writing the to `server.out` in the `current directory`.

The `current directory` of `init.d` is /etc/init.d (as mentioned by linusg).

Using absolute path for the output file (to a write-able location) will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the working directory for `init.d` services is `/etc/init.d`, see [How do I execute an arbitrary script with a working directory of the directory its in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363946/how-do-i-execute-an-arbitrary-script-with-a-working-directory-of-the-directory-i).

**Solutions:**

1. Use absolute paths in your Python code, like mentioned in the comments.
2. Before starting the Python script by `python start_server.py &`, change the working directory by a simple `cd /your/path/`.

Hope this helps!